# MODX FormIt validation checks only `required`

Tags: forms, validation, modx, modx-revolution, formit

I have a contact form on my site. I use formit for its FormIT validation. I want email be not more than 40 characters, be reqired and be correct email address. `Message` field is required too and has max length set.

Validator doesn't work correctly:

- When required fields are empty, it shows error message and doesn't allow to send the form (this situation is absolutely correct)
- When in `email` is **any** text (valid or not), form is sent but redirect to success page doesn't work (so it happens also when we enter more than max length)

  ```
      [[!FormIt?
      &hooks=`spam,email,redirect,FormItAutoResponder`
      &emailTpl=`emailTplContact`
      &emailSubject=`Message from site.com`
      &emailTo=`myemail@gmail.com`
      &validate=`email:email:required:maxLength=^40^,
                 message:required:maxLength=^150^`
      &redirectTo=`11`
      &fiarTpl=`emailAutoRespond`
      &fiarSubject=`Your message is sent`
      &fiarFromName=`My Site`
      &fiarFrom=`myemail@gmail.com`
      &fiarToField=`email`
      &fiarReplyTo=`email`
      ]]

      <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="[[~[[*id]]]]" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" role="form" data-toggle="validator" name="order">
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" type="name" placeholder="Name" value="[[!+fx.name]]" size=25>
        <input type="text" required="required" type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="[[!+fx.email]]">
        [[!+fx.error.email]]
        <textarea required="required" placeholder="Message" id="message" name="message">[[!+fx.message]]</textarea>
        <button name="send">Send</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  ```

Comment: it certainly appears you have everything set up correctly.  I would try to strip it down to see if it actually is validating the email field length:  [[!FormIt? &validate=`email:maxLength=^40^`   I know you are supposed to be able to chain multiple validators together, but it just might be having issues with the email:email:required:maxLength

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have type attribute twice in the name input and the email input, so that might be the problem.

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" type="name">
<input type="text" required="required" type="email">
```

Remove **type="name"** and **type="email"** -- (leave type="text")

Also - I have only ever used a prefix of **fi** for Formit placeholders; do you know for sure that **fx** will work? Did you set that somewhere else? You say you're seeing the error message so I guess the error placeholder must be working...

Be sure to add `placeholderPrefix` to your FormIt call:

```
[[!FormIt?
    &placeholderPrefix=`fx`
    &hooks=`spam,email,redirect,FormItAutoResponder`
    &emailTpl=`emailTplContact`
    &emailSubject=`Message from site.com`
    &emailTo=`myemail@gmail.com`
    &validate=`email:email:required:maxLength=^40^,
           message:required:maxLength=^150^`
    &redirectTo=`11`
    &fiarTpl=`emailAutoRespond`
    &fiarSubject=`Your message is sent`
    &fiarFromName=`My Site`
    &fiarFrom=`myemail@gmail.com`
    &fiarToField=`email`
    &fiarReplyTo=`email`
]]
```

Comment: The `fx` prefix will work as long as it's set in the FormIt call - which is doesn't seem to be in the code above. `&placeholderPrefix` lets you specify your own prefix.